# How to get a hook on an element when another element (not an ancestor) is targeted

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, sass

I've used the following selector to colorize an icon font icon (.toggler)  on click if #togglenav is targeted:

```
.toggler {
    color:orange;
}

body:not(:target) #togglenav:target .toggler {
    color: lighten(orange, 25%);
}
```

So the icon color is orange when the button isn't clicked and turned into a lightened orange variation when clicked. The html looked like the following:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="navio" id="togglenav" tabindex="0">
            <li><a href="#togglenav" class="icon-alone toggler" title="Menu open and close">
                <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="t"></span>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Menu open and close</span></a>
           </li>
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav1">Menu 1</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav2">Menu 2</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav3">Menu 3</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav4">Menu 4</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav5">Menu 5</a></li><!--
        --><li class="togglereset" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now i had to change the position of the .toggler class "a" element and placed it on the same level with the #togglenav unordered list.

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <a href="#togglenav" class="icon-alone toggler" title="Menu open and close">
        <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="t"></span>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Menu open and close</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="navio" id="togglenav" tabindex="0">
            <li><a class="navbase" href="#nav1">Menu 1</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav2">Menu 2</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav3">Menu 3</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav4">Menu 4</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav5">Menu 5</a></li><!--
        --><li class="togglereset" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Problem is now i am unable to get the hook on .toggler when #togglenav is in a targeted state. Since #togglenav isn't a ancestor of .toggler anymore the button stay orange all the time. Is there an elegant way to catch .toggler if #togglenav is targeted anyway? Best regards Ralf

Comment: Since `#toggleNav` is the same element as `.toggler` now, can't you just do `.toggler` for the orange state amd `.toggler:target` for the lightened state?

Comment: #togglenav and .toggler aren't identical unfortunately. .toggler is an a element and #togglenav an unordered list by clicking .toggler #togglenav is targeted as you can see in the href="#togglenav" of .toggler

Comment: Oops, I misread the href as the ID on .toggler.

Comment: FYI, the negation in `body:not(:target) #toggleNav:target` is redundant - there can only ever be one `:target` at a time, so if you're looking for `#toggleNav:target` then you can guarantee that `body` is `:not(:target)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.toggler` is now a preceding sibling of `#togglenav` and there is no preceding sibling selector, you can't select `.toggler` when `#togglenav` is in the targeted state with your new structure.

See if you can move `.toggler` *after* `#togglenav` and update your layout CSS accordingly:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="navio" id="togglenav" tabindex="0">
            <li><a class="navbase" href="#nav1">Menu 1</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav2">Menu 2</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav3">Menu 3</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav4">Menu 4</a></li><!--
        --><li><a class="navbase" href="#nav5">Menu 5</a></li><!--
        --><li class="togglereset" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#top">Back to top</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#togglenav" class="icon-alone toggler" title="Menu open and close">
        <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="t"></span>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Menu open and close</span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

If you can do that, then the selector to use would be `#togglenav:target + .toggler`. As stated in my comment, I left out `body:not(:target)` because it's redundant when you've already designated a different element as `:target`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Haven't thought of an adjacent selector for solving that problem... An elegant solution, thanks!!!